# Where can I submit a bug for the Play Store or Google Play Services?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, android-inapp-purchase

I don't know exactly where the bug lies, I think it is on the Play Store but I guess it could be Google Play Services.

Basically a user with accounts X and Y on their phone will make an in-app purchase on my app with account X. Then I will do a staged rollout of an update and that user who had the app installed as account X all of the sudden will get the update for account Y and the app will not recognize the in-app item as purchased.

I have talked with another developer with a similar in-app model and they experience the same bug.

Where do I submit that bug?

Answer (score 3):

If you think it is a bug. You create an issue in the [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list). The proper person from Google team will look into your issue there, and will check if it really is a bug or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a bug, specially considering other developers experience it as well. Anyways, I don't see on that list an option for Google Play Services of the Play Store.

Comment: I think you could file it there because Google Play services and in-app billing is part of Android. You could choose "Developer bug report". What's important is that they will see the bug. Good luck!

Comment: In my experience any Google Play Services related bugs opened in the AOSP tracker will be closed, and no information will be provided on where to actually file the bug.

Comment: You could also try emailing the support team for Google Play Services.

Comment: Exactly what @Eliezer said! I posted a bug for Google Play Services that's pretty serious and this was the response I got "This website is for developer issues with the AOSP Android source code and the developer toolset, not Google apps or services such as Google Play Services or GMS. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an appropriate place to report these issues. All I can say is that this isn't it, sorry. Try posting on the Google Product Forums instead. Thanks."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, currently at the bottom of https://support.google.com/googleplay/community one can post issues.